# ASP.NET MVC How do i close fancybox on form post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fancybox

I have a fancybox popup with a form inside it. When the form is posted it all works fine BUT after it is posted it redirects to the view and shows it on a full page.

What i want is for the popup for to be posted and the fancy box to be closed.

Here is my code

**Main Page** This opens the popup fine

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Add Person Box", "AddTest", Nothing, New With {.class = "fbox"})%>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".fbox").fancybox();

        });
    </script>
```

Popup page

```
<% Using Html.BeginForm() %>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Person" />

<% End Using %>
```

Again this submits fine but redirects to itself in full screen mode. i just want the form to be posted and the fancy box to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the attribute `onsubmit="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();""` to your `form` tag

Comment: i tried that but the form does not submit and the fancybox does not close either

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the redirect, you need to make it a web method.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery ajax to post the content of the Popup form. Once you get the response from your server action method, close it with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the JQuery Form plugin. Hijack the form and do an ajax request. After the request is complete, you can just close the fancy box from the callback function (as long as there were no errors).

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

```
// bind to the form's submit event 
$('#myForm2').submit(function() { 
    // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first 
    // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
       success : function (result) { $.fancybox.close() }
    }); 

    // !!! Important !!! 
    // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
    return false; 
});
```